# Android: changing colors gradually for multiple imageview backgrounds using seekbar

Tags: java, android

I am using background color on an imageview to make a rectangle color and I want to to morph gradually to a lighter color using the seekbar by removing an R G or B from the hex color. How can I do this without writing a million lines of code?
This is an example of what I want it to do, experimenting with one box though.
https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/cmsc436/Labs/ModernArtUI/modernUI.mp4

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            if (i >= 25 && i < 50) {
                imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            } else if (i >= 50 && i < 75) {
                imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else if (i >= 75 && i <= 100) {
                imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            } else {
                imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
```

Answer found:

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                iv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0xFF, i, i, 200));
}
```

Depending on what color you want, set the max on the seekbar to 255 and you can play around with the numbers to get your desired color at a gradual change. Also great reference when trying to find the color http://www.tayloredmktg.com/rgb/

Comment: `GradientDrawable` can take care of drawing linear gradients for you, if you supply it the base colors. While you can only provide it a maximum of three colors when defining in XML, the actual implementation in Java has no such limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            iv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0xFF, i, i, 200));
}
```

Depending on what color you want, set the max on the seekbar to 255 and you can play around with the numbers to get your desired color at a gradual change. Also great reference when trying to find the color http://www.tayloredmktg.com/rgb/

Answer (score 3):

There is no single correct way. It depends on how you want to traverse the spectrum of color.

One option:

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

        float hue = i/100f;
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.HSVToColor( new float[]{ hue, 1f, 0.75f } ) );
    }
```

Another (less graceful) option would be

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        double increment = 0xFFFFFFd / 100d;
        int color = i * increment;

        imageView.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, how would I edit the first option to go from like a blue to a yellowish color? or something very similar to this video https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/cmsc436/Labs/ModernArtUI/modernUI.mp4

Comment: I would suggest reading up on color theory. It is important to understand what you are doing, and not just copying and pasting other people's code. This is especially true when you are enrolled in a course to learn it (as the link above would indicate). Perhaps you can start your reading here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV